# How to work with components in Angular in more advance way

Tags: angular, frontend

I created a component that I use several times in other different components. In my case, the behavior of the child should depend on which parent component it is in, in my case, the child component should call different services.
I am not able to come up with anything smarter than a large number of booleans and conditions, an example is below.
[Parents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPD3M.png) /
[Example of how child components is placed in parent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DORuO.png) /
[Another example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieTLF.png) /
[child's arguments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ug9Sd.png) /
As you can see here are boolean arguments that indicate where exactly the child is located. This is done in order not to create several children files, the differences in which are minimal, but this generates conditions like that.
[the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZF9w.png) /
[the problem2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4k2yp.png)

Github: https://github.com/Comet1nc/keep-notes

Is there any way to get rid of these conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding an `@Input()` property to the `NoteFieldComponent` for each parent component, you could try adding an `@Output()` property for each action the user can trigger. The parent components can listen to the events emitted by the `NoteFieldComponent` and execute their specific logic.

This way the child component doesn't have to know what it's parent component is, which means it doesn't have to change whenever you want to use it in a new parent component.

Comment: thanks, it helped, but I completely forgot about the conditions in the html file of the child, do you have any ideas how to remove them?

Comment: [Content projection](https://angular.io/guide/content-projection) might be a solution, it enables you to project different content into a child component from within the parent component. This way the child component still doesn't have to know inside of which parent component it's being used, it just has to provide slots for content to be projected into.